# Azure AD B2C to authenticate corporate Azure AD accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Azure AD B2C newbie here. I have a Single Page Application hosted in Azure & it uses Azure Functions. I want to allow users in many organisations to login to my application using their existing corporate email address, & authenticated in their company's Azure AD, which I have no access to.

For instance I want people in company Contoso to access my Azure SPA by logging in with their existing Contoso email addresses "john.smith@contoso.com". Authentication takes place in Contoso's Azure AD.

Do I use the Azure AD B2C Identity Experience Framework & Custom Policy for this? Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't the best case for use of Azure AD B2C.

I recommend you use [the "multi-tenant" pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview) to configure your single-page application to accept sign-ins from any Azure Active Directory tenant

Comment: And if you need to restrict access to only specific tenants, you'll need to add checks on your application's side. The `tid` claim will contain the id for the Azure AD tenant.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. To setup Tenant Restrictions using the tid claim, is it normal practice to request the customer's Azure AD tenant id that they will use for sign-in? I don't see any other way to add their tid to a list of subscribers. Thank you